# checking if the parameter has get data in C# Web API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

How to set nested if query by checking the parameter if data exist.
Based on the project that I am working there will be a return statement of different error code of "400"

If string chart_type is missing it will return an error of "Invalid chart type to access data."
If string kpi_name is missing it will return an error of "Invalid kpi name to access data."
If string entity_name is missing it will return an error of "Invalid entity name to access data."

If there is no data found it will return an error of "No data found for requested parameters."
If the required parameter is missing it will return an error of "Required parameters missing to access data".

Lastly if the user is not authorized to access the api it will return an error of 401 "This request is unauthorized"

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage gethistogram(string entity_name, string kpi_name, string chart_type, int unix_start, int unix_end, string language)
{

   var result = _definitionRepository.histogram(entity_name,kpi_name,chart_type,unix_start,unix_end,language);

   if (chart_type == null)
   {
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid chart Type to access data");
   }

   if (kpi_name == null)
   {
     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid KPI name to access data");
   }

   if (entity_name == null)
   {
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Entity name to access data");
   }

   if (kpi_name == null && chart_type == null && entity_name == null)
   {
     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Required parameters missing to access data");
   }

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

Comment: Whats the issue that you have with the Method?

Comment: Pass data through model, and validate model state in a validation filter. That's it.

Comment: If I enter the the wrong value the method will still continue to proceed. I just want to achieve that all my supplied parameters will be returned accurate. 

but the result will be blank "[ ]" and doesn't display my error code in the method.

I'm assuming that my root problem is  that my parameter is == null, 
it doesn't validate if the actual data supplied is in the database.

Comment: Hi Div, can you give some examples I'm quite new in web api

Answer (score 0):

you are starting the `_definitionRepository.histogram(` before any parameter is validated.

It should be executed after validations :

```
if (kpi_name == null && chart_type == null && entity_name == null) // this check must be first
                return ...
if (chart_type == null)
                return ...
if (kpi_name == null)
                return ...
if (entity_name == null)
                return ...
// all checks were passed so you can get the histogram            
var result = _definitionRepository.histogram(entity_name,kpi_name,chart_type,unix_start,unix_end,language);

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
```

401 (authentication error) is raised by the controller (or method) marked with [Authorize] automatically. 
However you [should configure the web host authentication somehow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api). 
It can be done using the code in the Startup.cs or by the web server (IIS) configuration

Comment: Hi sir, I've tried to follow your format and I've tried to insert wrong data but still it returns with an status code of OK, though it returns no value  such as  "[ ]", so there are no error handling.

Comment: sounds strange since `if (chart_type == null) return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);` should return badrequest if chart_type is null. Please change `chart_type == null` condition to `string.IsNullOrEmpty(chart_type)` and try to test it again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want exactly, but you can try the following for validation before your method will be processed.

First, declare your YourFilter attribute as shown below,

```
public class YourFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var yourParams = context.ActionArguments;
        //do your validation, control
    }
}
```

Then you can use this attribute as,

```
[YourFilter] //=>HERE
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage gethistogram(string entity_name, string kpi_name, string chart_type, int unix_start, int unix_end, string language)
{
...
```